# How to create properties to and object dynamically based on another object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where from a `source` object I need to create a new `result` object.

The object would need to have exactly all properties from `source`, with the addition of "methods", with naming based on the properties and code to be executed based on a template (in my case `alert(this.x)`).

Note: script should keep in consideration any number of properties from `source`

I would like to know:

- Is it possible to do it in JS?
- What the appropriate Technics?
- Any examples?

FROM SOURCE OBJECT

```
  var source = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b'
    };
```

I NEED TO GET RESULT OBJ DYNAMICALLY CREATED (BY SOME FUNCTION)

```
    var result = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        _setA: function(){
            alert(this.a);
        },
        _setB: function(){
            alert(this.a);
        }
    }
```

Note: result is created after processing the source object

EDIT:

final solution based on your answers

http://jsfiddle.net/kbnd6e5c/1/

Comment: just for clarification the object result should be created dynamically based on source properties

Comment: Should later mutations to `source` be reflected when calling the methods on `result`?

Comment: @sixfingeredman no reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method to copy properties, and then you need iterate through properties and create dynamic setters. For example like in below code:

```
var source = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };    
var result = $.extend({}, source);

Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
    result['_set' + key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = function(value) {
        alert(this.key);
        this[key] = value;
    }
});
```

Check the working demo below.

```js
var source = { a: 'a', b: 'b', test: 'test' };    
var result = $.extend({}, source);
    
Object.keys(source).forEach(function(key) {
    result['_set' + key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = function(value) {
        this[key] = value;
    }
});

alert([ result.a, result.test ]);

result._setA('a1');
result._setTest('test1');

alert([ result.a, result.test ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I need the  _setA and _setB created dynamically based on the properties in source

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have fully understanding your question but I think you should juste use that simple thing:

```
var copy = result
copy.example = {
    x: Y,
    z, T
}
copy.newFuntion = function(){...} //add your own function
```

This way you have everything that result have + your own things

Comment: copy is not, its a reference, appending to it will also append to the source

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var result = {
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B'
};

var copy = result;

Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    Object.defineProperty(copy, "_set" + key, {
        get: function() {
            return result[key]; 
        }
    })
});

copy._seta;
copy._setb;
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: hi, thanks, but it is not for getting or setting property is for creating dynamically method with some code to be executed inside.